# moment.js diff showing wrong result

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am working on a small script using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), that shows me how many hours and minutes (seperate) I have until a specific hour. But for some reason the result is wrong.

**Thats my code so far:**

```
var TimeA = moment('08:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');
var TimeB = moment('16:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');

var DiffAB = moment(TimeA.diff(TimeB)).format('HH:mm:ss');

var DiffHours = moment(DiffAB, 'HH:mm:ss').format('H');
var DiffMinutes = moment(DiffAB, 'HH:mm:ss').format('mm');

console.log('TimeA: ' + moment(TimeA).format('HH:mm:ss'));
console.log('TimeB: ' + moment(TimeB).format('HH:mm:ss'));

console.log('Difference A-B: ' + DiffAB);

console.log('Diff Hours: ' + DiffHours);
console.log('Diff Minutes: ' + DiffMinutes);
```

**And thats the Output:**

```
TimeA: 08:00:00
TimeB: 16:00:00
Difference A-B: 17:00:00
Diff Hours: 17
Diff Minutes: 00
```

The difference of `A - B` should be `8` but its showing `17`.

Comment: `TimeA.diff(TimeB)` returns number of milliseconds.  `moment(Number)` interprets the argument as the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.  So you're probably seeing that interpreted into your local timezone.

Comment: Moment can be confusing at times. You are not using using diff() correctly and as mentioned, without parameters it returns Unix timestamp. Please take a look here --> [moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per momentjs documentation

> If the moment is earlier than the moment you are passing to moment.fn.diff, the return value will be negative.

To translate it to your example:

> If TimeA is earlier than TimeB passed to moment.diff then the value will be negative

and since it's returned as milliseconds `-28800000` is an instruction like: take that amount of miliseconds from midnight, that gives you the different time

so what you should be doing is

```
var DiffAB = moment(TimeB.diff(TimeA)).utcOffset(0).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Diff documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Example from doc

> An easy way to think of this is by replacing .diff( with a minus operator.

```
          // a < b
a.diff(b) // a - b < 0
b.diff(a) // b - a > 0
```

Comment: The output is now `Difference A-B: 09:00:00` but it should be `08:00:00`.

Comment: What timezone you are in, is one of the date localised?

Comment: This solution combined with the solution of @Bogdan Kuštan is giving the right result.

Comment: I see, I've run the check and in GMT+1 it does return 17:00 since it's the 16 hours localised to your timezone, i've extened my answer with a solution

Answer (score -1):

As everyone said, `diff` returns milliseconds, so you should convert it to hours (or desired format).

```
moment.duration(TimeA.diff(TimeB), 'milliseconds').asHours();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var TimeA = moment('08:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss');
var TimeB = moment('16:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss'); 
var DiffAB = moment.utc(moment(TimeB).diff(moment(TimeA)));
console.log('Difference B-A: ' + DiffAB.format('HH:mm:ss'));
console.log('Diff Hours: ' + DiffAB.format('H'));
console.log('Diff Minutes: ' + DiffAB.format('s'));
```